# how to get redshift to recognize the correct format of timestamp in external table of parquet files

Tags: amazon-redshift, parquet

I am converting dates in a parquet file like this:

```
    timestamp_column = next((col for col in df.columns if 'timestamp' in col), None)
    
    if timestamp_column:
        # Convert epoch to datetime
        df[key.split('/')[0] + '_' + key.split('/')[1][:-1] + '_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df[timestamp_column], unit='s')
```

The timestamps look good in the parquet file, although i don't see the datatype:

```
   hash  number  \
0  0xe0594250efac73640aeff78ec40aaaaa87f91edb54e5...       1   

  arbitrum_block_timestamp  
0      2021-05-28 23:09:04  ...
```

So I create an external table with timestamp, but when I select it it doesn't like that there's only seconds in the timestamps, it's expecting format '2021-05-28 23:09:04.123456' with microseconds I think. So it puts the dates way in the future:

```
dev=# select arbitrum_block_timestamp from arbitrum_schema.processed_arbitrum_blocks limit 5;
   arbitrum_block_timestamp   
------------------------------
 283525-04-29 11:22:00.358354
 285180-04-08 11:48:40.358354
 283523-07-21 07:48:40.358354
 285188-05-31 00:42:00.358354
 283157-09-26 05:08:40.358354
(5 rows)
```

With COPY there's options like `TIMEFORMAT AS 'xx..'`, but I don't see how to do this in my table creation:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE arbitrum_schema.processed_arbitrum_blocks(
...
arbitrum_block_timestamp TIMESTAMP
)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION 's3://bloc...ocks/';
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a predefined schema(pyarrow) to save pandas dataframe. Without it, I didn't find a solution.

```py
df.created_at = pd.to_datetime(df.created_at, errors='coerce')
schema = pa.schema([
    ('created_at', pa.timestamp('s'),
     other_columns
])
df.to_parquet(schema=schema)
```

In table creation, I used `timestamp` type